# Smoothen hover animation using setInterval() will flicker and won't stop

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make an element chase my cursor using `event.clientX` on `mouseover`. To make it smoother, [I read](https://javascript.info/js-animation) that an option is to use `setInterval()`.

That's what I tried:

```
class Home extends Component {

    state = {
        left: 0
    };

    timer;

    ...

    onMouseLeave = (index) => {
        const ref = document.querySelector('.hover-text-' + index);
        ref.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove);
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    };

    onMouseMove = _.throttle((event) => {
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({left: event.clientX})
        }, 20);
    });

    ...

    render() {
        const style = {
            top: this.state.top + 'px',
            left: this.state.left + 'px',
        };

        return (
            <div className="container-fluid container-home d-flex justify-content-center">
                <ul>
                    {this.list.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={index} style={{marginTop: index !== 0 ? 'mt-2' : null}}>
                                ...
                                <div id="moving-image" className={this.classList({
                                    'moving-image': true,
                                    'image-outer-container': true,
                                    [`hover-text-image-${index}`]: true,
                                    'invisible': this.state.hoveredItem !== index,
                                })}
                                style={style}>
                                    <ImageHolder image={item.image}/>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The result is that the element starts to flicker horrendously, won't stop and makes my Laptop explode. How so? How can I prevent that from happening and realize my desire behavior?

Comment: Throttling, Debouncing is the thing you are search for, check this https://medium.com/gyanworthy/debouncing-vs-throttling-in-javascript-904ac90109df

Comment: Just added debouncing: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce but this obviously make the image jump from value to value. How can I smoothen this?

Comment: I believe you need `Throttling` not `Debounce`,  `Debounce` will block and discard the animation call, `Throttling` on the other hand will, sort of but not exactly, will queue your code execution. its very simple to implement, the example I linked use native js to build the animation on `mouseMove`.

Comment: @mamounothman using a higher throttle value will also cause jumps. I'm trying to achieve the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59755752/decelerate-on-mouseover-moving-content-using-js --- Had a different code snippet back then.